# Rendering problem in Android Studio when writing files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a very simple code that writes to a file like this -

```
val path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath + "/user_id"
var file = File(path)
file.writeText("user id")
```

This works without a problem on emulator.

However, when i'm editing this on Android Studio, the rendering of the layout.xml I'm using (that invokes the code above) fails, citing an error on the `file.writeText` code line

More specifically, I get this exception on the callstack -

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\user_id (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

So in other words, the code above works well in emulator, but not inside Android Studio layout preview.

Anyone has any thoughts on this item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout preview is rendering views. The only reason I can think of why this code would be running in the Android Studio layout preview is because:

- You wrote a custom view (which is fine), and
- That custom view is trying to do disk I/O (which is not fine)

So, the best solution is to move the disk I/O to something more appropriate (e.g., a repository object).

If you are sure that you want to keep that code where it is, wrap it in [a check for `isInEditMode()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#isineditmode) and do not do the I/O if you are in edit mode. That means the code is running in an IDE, and many things on `Context`, such as `getExternalFilesDir()`, will not work.